# Counting and grouping columns with multiple JOIN's

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

I have 3 tables:

```
          Table A
----------------------------
  id   |  data
----------------------------
   1      nothing important
   2      nothing important
   3      nothing important
```

```
          Table B
-----------------------------------------
  id   |  table_a_id   |   table_c_id
-----------------------------------------
   1         1                1
   2         1                2
   3         1                3
```

```
          Table C
----------------------------
  id   |  name
----------------------------
   1      Bob Saget
   2      Neil deGrasse Tyson
   3      Mike Tyson
```

Table B and C are 1:1 relationship, whereas Table A and Table B are a one to many relationship.

**I want to get a count of the `JOIN`ed rows in `Table B`.**

Here is my attempt that does not work:

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS count, tC.name FROM table_a tA 
LEFT JOIN table_b tB ON tA.id = tB.table_a_id
LEFT JOIN table_c tC ON tC.id = tB.table_c_id
GROUP BY tA.id, tC.name
```

This is what I'm hoping the result will look like:

```
          Result
----------------------------
  count  |  name
----------------------------
   3        Bob Saget
   3        Neil deGrasse Tyson
   3        Mike Tyson
```

Count represents the number of rows that were `JOIN`ed from `Table B`. In this case, 3 rows from table B carry a foreign key for table A.

Use can [use this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db4823/1).

Comment: You are using only inner joins therefore only the record with ID 1 from table a is ever put into the resultset. The count(1) of the joined rows imO is correct, I don't understand your expectations.

Comment: @aschoerk I've updated my expectations and included a fiddle.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try GROUP BY tC.name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many rows in `a` relate to each `c`, then `c` has to come first in the `from` clause, followed by `left join`s to the other tables.

Also, you need to `a.id` from the `group by` clause - otherwise, you would probably get just one (or zero) row per group.

Other things to consider:

- you are `left join`ing, so you should count something from `a` rather than just `count(*)`, so you get `0` for unmatched rows (instead of `1` with `count(*)`)
- I would recommend grouping by the primary key of `c` rather than on the `name`, in case two different `id`s might have the same `name`

So:

```
SELECT count(a.id) AS count, c.name 
FROM table_c c 
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON c.id = b.table_c_id
LEFT JOIN table_a a ON a.id = b.table_a_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: I've made these changes but the count on `a.id` is still resulting in 1.

Comment: @user0000001: my bad, I forgot to fix the ordering of the tables in the `from` clause. Done now.

Comment: I am still getting 1 for the count. Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db4823/1).

Comment: @user0000001: now, I don't get why you want `3` in the resultset. As of now, each row in `c` has just one match in `a`. Are you looking for a total count of matches (which means that all rows will always have the same count - here `3`)?

Comment: That's correct. I'm trying to get the number of unique entries in `table_b` that hold a foreign key to `table_a`. At the same time, I also need those unique entries.